# Display loading image before JavaFX WebView loads the page

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am using JavaFX 2.2 in a desktop application and I have implemented the WebView component. From the desktop application I have loaded www.google.com. The problem is that I wish to show a .gif image before the page loads. Now, it shows a white screen and then the page.
Is there a way of doing this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can listen to `WebEngine#loadWorker.stateProperty` and show an animated gif above `WebView` until loading is ready.

Even better, IMHO, would be to listen to `WebEngine#loadWorker.progressProperty` and show real loading progress to user.

```
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    final ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(); // or you can use ImageView with animated gif instead

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    root.getChildren().addAll(webView, progress);
    final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
    engine.load("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094264/display-loading-image-before-javafx-webview-loads-the-page");

    // updating progress bar using binding
    progress.progressProperty().bind(engine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());

    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                         // hide progress bar then page is ready
                         progress.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });


    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: on loading big html progress not showing, is there any work around ?